# Custom table headers

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I would like to make a table (it is enough to display it in the layout) in ArcGIS that would have the attached field (column) structure.
Is it possible and how? I can use ArcPy, preferably.
[image]

Edit: Something like MultiIndex for columns
https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.05-hierarchical-indexing.html

Comment: What have you tried? For example Insert - Object - Excel, create the table in excel.

Comment: I need to do it with Python, since I am creating a toolbox that would output a table with that structure for a polygon layer. I have not tried anything yet.